# Get comma separated values in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have a file with multiple lines like the following string. I need to extract the values of id and obj.

```
{"Class":"ZONE","id":"DEV100.ZN301","name":"3109 E BTM","zgroup":"EAST FLOOR 3","prog":"","members":[{"obj":"DEV300.WC3"},{"obj":"DEV300.WC4"},{"obj":"DEV300.WC7"},{"obj":"DEV300.WC10"}]}
```

I am using the following command to obtain the output:

```
[user@server ~]$ cat file.txt | grep "\"Class\":\"ZONE\"" | while IFS="," read -r a b c d e f ; do echo "$b$f";done | grep ZN301
```

Output:

```
"id":"DEV100.ZN301""members":[{"obj":"DEV300.WC3"},{"obj":"DEV300.WC4"},{"obj":"DEV300.WC7"},{"obj":"DEV300.WC10"}]}
```

My aim is to get the following **Output:**

```
DEV100.ZN301 : DEV300.WC3 , DEV300.WC4 , DEV300.WC7 , DEV300.WC10
```

Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: The sane way to do this is to use `jq`. Trying to parse JSON with tools that don't understand its syntax is innately error-prone.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the program generating your files suddenly starts, say, sorting the keys, to make the lines instead look like `{"Class":"ZONE","id":"DEV100.ZN301","members":[{"obj":"DEV300.WC3"},{"obj":"DEV300.WC4"},{"obj":"DEV300.WC7"},{"obj":"DEV300.WC10"}],"name":"3109 E BTM","prog":"","zgroup":"EAST FLOOR 3"}`, that would have exactly the same semantics for any compliant JSON parser, but would break your code that depends on ordering utterly. And that kind of thing can happen just with library version changes and no code updates to the tool itself at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq -r 'select(.Class == "ZONE") | (.id + " : " + ([.members[] | .obj] | join(" , ")))'
```

...or, leaning on a Python interpreter:

```
parse_json() {
  python -c '
import sys, json
for line in sys.stdin:
  line = line.strip()    # ignore trailing newlines
  if not line: continue  # skip blank lines
  doc = json.loads(line)
  if doc.get("Class") != "ZONE":
    continue
  line_id = doc.get("id")
  objs = [m.get("obj") for m in doc.get("members", [])]
  sys.stdout.write("%s : %s\n" % (line_id, " , ".join(objs)))
'
}

parse_json
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Charles, but I cannot install custom packages on the machines and i have 1000s of such machines. So I am trying to get a shell command that will help me out.